# What the "Reads" Column in Profiler exactly mean?

Tags: sql-server, profiler

Can any one explain, whats the "Reads" column in SQL Server Profiler exactly mean ?

Why sum of logical reads get by **SET STATISTICS IO ON** are different from number of reads in SQL Profiler?

Which other types of reads are added in SQL Profiler to show?

Comment: I believe profiler reads will always be >= sum of stats I/O (or at the very least I have never seen them equal - there may even be some edge case where trace < stats I/O). Trace has reads tracked by session, not by table or by operator like you’ll see in an execution plan. Some reads come from other places than the tables in your query (especially when you’re running trace, set statistics io, retrieving execution plans, etc.)